# Getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined(anonymous function) when trying to bind data to Kendo Grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo grid that is being generated in an external javascript file as well as having data bound to it, and I been getting

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'uid' of undefined(anonymous function)

I have no idea where this 'uid' is coming from, I have been stepping through the code and and I think the error is coming in when trying to pass the returned data to the datasource of the grid.
My grid is this (and the grid does appear in the view)

```
    function ShowAdministratorsGrid() {
    $("#adminGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:[{
            data: GetAdministratorsInformation()
        }],
        columns: [{
            field: "AdministratorName",
            title: "AdministratorName"
        },
        {
            field: "DateCreated",
            title: "DateCreated"
        },
        {
            field: "CreatedBy",
            title: "CreatedBy"
        }],
        Scrollable: true,
        Sortable: true,
        Pageable: [{
            Refresh: true,
            PageSizes: true,
            ButtonCount: 5
        }],
        Selectable: true,
        Events: function (e) {
            e.onRowSelect();
        }
    })
}
```

The datasource data is this

```
    function GetAdministratorsInformation() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: AddURLParam.AddGetAdminInformationURL,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            GetAdministratorData(data);
        }
    })
}
```

The GetAdministratorData function is this..

```
    function GetAdministratorData(admindata) {
    administratorName = admindata.administratorName,
    dateCreated = admindata.dateCreated,
    createdBy = admindata.createdBy
}
```

I am getting the returned data, as you can see in ScreenShot1

[image: ScreenShot1 Data is there]

If you take a look at ScreenShot2, I am getting an undefined when adding the returned values to the GetAdministratorData, here is the screenshot
[image: ScreenShot2]

So I am thinking that is why I am getting the error on populating the KendoGrid, does anyone see what I am doing wrong or where things are going wrong?

**EDIT**

I narrowed down where the error is being thrown..
[image: Where the error is being thrown]

Comment: @Jan, I just noticed those comma's, i fixed that part and its still coming back as undefined like in ScreenShot2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is an array. so you need to access the item by `admindata[0].administratorName`.

Or loop through the array, I don't really know what you're trying to do. In any case, `data` is an array, which (right now) just contains the one object.

Also, on this line

```
dataSource:[{
        data: GetAdministratorsInformation()
}],
```

`GetAdministratorsInformation` doesn't really return anything since it's an async operation. If you want to set the data, you'll need to do it on your success callback in `GetAdministratorsInformation`

And in your `columns` settings, the field names are pascal case `AdministratorName` while in the data object they're camel case `administratorName`

To recap:

```
function CreateAdministratorsKendoGrid(administratorData) {
    $("#adminGrid").kendoGrid({
        dataSource:[{
            data: administratorData
        }],
        columns: [{
            field: "administratorName",
            title: "Administrator name"
        },
        {
            field: "dateCreated",
            title: "Date created"
        },
        {
            field: "createdBy",
            title: "Created by"
        }],
        Scrollable: true,
        Sortable: true,
        Pageable: [{
            Refresh: true,
            PageSizes: true,
            ButtonCount: 5
        }],
        Selectable: true,
        Events: function (e) {
            e.onRowSelect();
        }
    })
}

function InitializeAdministratorsGrid() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: AddURLParam.AddGetAdminInformationURL,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            CreateAdministratorsKendoGrid(data);
        }
    })
}

InitializeAdministratorsGrid();
```

Comment: Ok that was fixed, I am getting the values now, thank you for pointing that out, I appreciate it. But I am getting that error still that I mentioned in the question

Comment: Then you'll need to do some more digging to find the cause of that error (which I'm guessing is something entirely different)

Comment: I agree, and I have been for a couple hours before I posted the question and am unsure where to look for the issue

Comment: I just noticed your edit now...It worked like a charm and thank you for explaining what I was doing wrong, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved issue as follow:

```
var objectDDL = e.container.find("select:eq(0)").data("kendoDropDownList");
var rows = jQuery.makeArray(objectDDL.dataSource.data());
$.each(rows, function (index, value) {
  objectDDL.dataSource.remove(rows[index]);
});
```